# Commerce Kickstart 2 Admin Functions Extremely Slow Shared Hosting

Tags: 7, commerce, performance

I'm having a problem similar to some others posted here: Extremely slow performance in Admin for certain operations, most notably: Adding an Order or saving a View. Basically, it -feels- like SQL Queries that -insert- more complex kinds of data cause issues.

Unlike other posts I've read, I'm on shared Linux hosting.

The odd thing is that we have a production site on (Ubercart) on D6 which is on the same physical server, but is -not- having issues like this at all.

I have contacted the hosting company and they assure me that the MySQL and PHP settings are the same for both the D7 (slow) site and the D6 (fast) site.

1. What are my options for troubleshooting this?
2. Is this a known problem specific to Commerce and/or D7?

Just to be clear: The visitor face of the site works fine. For example, if I add an order from the actual site, it works as expected. The same operation from the Admin might take 30 seconds.

TIA.

Comment: Fairly broad question; try some of the database tips starting at [slide #74](https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1AgnurTWsWdMAFjfFmSU7mk2zfJu8jG_KmVdZ7-o6Pok/edit#slide=id.g385c64257_0214) from my DIY Drupal 7 Performance presentation

Comment: THANKS! I haven't gone through the entire thing in detail yet, but I appreciate it. I realise the mandate here are questions with a single specific answer, but ya gotta start -somewhere-. I'm surprised that some of those things eg. https://www.drupal.org/node/2263365 are not already 'standard equipment'.